# WooCommerce Dev Tools/Environment/Debugger

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am working on developing a hook to parse orders after they are created using PHP.

I am trying to work out the code prior to implementing the hook in order to not have to create lots of test orders and take the site offline while testing.

The only way I have found to test the wc_get_order and subsequent calls necessary is to create a function in my plug-in and assign a short code to it and then embed that short code into a test page.  Doing it this way is time consuming, error prone and tedious.

I am sure there has to be a better/faster/easier way to do this but I am not finding it.

Over the last 20 years of development projects I have grown used to full featured editors, tools and debuggers with breakpoints, step-through, etc.

Does something like this exist for the WooCommerce world, or is there a better way to code/debug/test than what I am doing now?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can't you just use [Webhooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/) or the [API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)?

Comment: For example [PHPUnit and WordPress](https://www.google.fr/search?q=PHPUnit+and+wordpress&oq=PHPUnit+and+wordpress) … WordPress Uses PHP… so you can also use anything related to PHP for Dev Tools/Environment/Debugger

Comment: BenM… I am using the webhooks (wc_get_order) unless you mean something different.

Comment: What I am having trouble with is determining what the error is that is causing the call to fail.  Don't know if it is in the call or in subsequent code or the return value.

Comment: LoicTheAztec… I understand I can use PHP tools for the PHP coding (editor), but not for debugging on WooCommerce as far as I know.